# Chef server on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, chef-infra

I need to install Chef, but it must use not PostgreSQL that come with the package, I want to use MongoDB.

So i have several questions:
How I understood it, Postgres is installed when I perform  `$ sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure`.
How do I exclude installing on Postgres from chef server without breaking the install off other needed components? Or I just install, run reconfigure and than redirect Chef Server to use MongoDB, if so, how can I get chef starting to use mongoDB?

Comment: Why do  you want to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about modifying the internal components of a specific product, and not about programming.

Comment: We wanted to create a CMDB on MondoDB and also a watched a presentation about Chef on Mongo and Python and it was pritty interesting so we decided that our CMDB and Chef could use the same MongoDb server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was only a little more than a year ago Opscode decided to move from CouchDB to PostgreSQL. CouchDB shared many similarities with MongoDB. Even if there's a particular compelling reason you'd like Chef server to run on MongoDB, I don't think the current framework would support it. Read more here http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/02/15/the-making-of-erchef-the-chef-11-server/

Comment: Thanks, probably your right. Than I'll stick to the idea for separate using of DB's